# Why won't coding keys or keyDecodingStrategy work?

Tags: json, swift, model, decoding

I'm trying to build an easy app in which a user searches for GitHub repositories but I'm failing with the request as I cannot properly decode JSON. I have a model I called "Search" and if I name the fields using snake_case notation, the decoding works. However, I would like to have camelCase notation and use decodingKeys or 
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
but none seems to work and I'm wondering why

Here's my code i.e. request execution:

```
open class GetRepositoriesRequest: Request {

    var query: String
    public var headers: [String: String] = [:]
    public var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
    public var method: RequestMethod = .GET
    public var apiAdress: String

    public init(query: String) {
        self.query = query
        self.apiAdress = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=\(self.query)"
    }

    public func execute() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let url = URL(string: self.apiAdress)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = self.method.rawValue
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data,response,error in
            do {
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                if let jsonResult = try? decoder.decode(Search.self, from: data) {
                    print(jsonResult)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

and models:

```
struct Search: Codable {
    var totalCount: Double
    var incompleteResults: Bool
    var items: [Item]

    public enum SearchKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let node_id:String
    let name: String
    let full_name: String
    let owner: Owner
}

struct Owner: Codable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let node_id:String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, I found an answer myself. I guess I totally forgot about other models not being in camelCase notation. Sorry for that